# how to add new item to CruiseControl.NET web dashboard

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

In one of my config files I am setting a property which differentiate production and development build , the CCNet is configured in a way that switching between these two require a CCNet restart, what I want to achieve is display this value somewhere in the web-dashboard, I am rather new to CCNet so any pointers will be appreciated.
/G

Answer (score 2):

I've used parameters to ask for input when the build is being run. I used them so the testers would be able to deploy the build of v1.4 or v1.5 to their test environment. This might do what you want.

I used something like the [CCNET parameters](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Example_from_Pierre_Jacomet) block to ask for the input.